# Is there any way to force the portrait screen even the hard keyboard is popped?

Tags: android

I specified an activity to be portrait-only in menifest file:

```
<activity android:name="mytest"
              android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

But it won't work on Droid when its hard keyboard is popped out.

When hard keyboard is popped out, the device always renders the layout of the activity in landscape orientation first, then it switches it back to portrait orientation. How can I let the app only render the activity in portrait orientation?

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I just want to add that this is a bad idea because there are Android smartbooks that are landscape-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your activity description

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```